# An object of two arrays to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have data like this:

```
var data = {
  value1: ["a", "b", "c"],
  value2: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I want to convert it to:

```
var newData = [
  {value1: "a", value2: 1},
  {value1: "b", value2: 2},
  {value1: "c", value2: 3}
]
```

How can I achieve this with javascript?

Comment: Are you open to lodash/underscore?

Comment: Loop over `value1`, and push little objects made from the value from `value1` and the value from `value2` at the same index onto an array.

Comment: Are the names `value1` and `value2` fixed?

Comment: @torazaburo I do not want to use lodash or underscore, and value1 and value2 are not fixed.

Comment: Are the lengths of the individual arrays guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: @torazaburo yea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a complete dynamic version for it, without giving keys.

It works for arrays with unequal length as well.

```js
function pivot(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, k) {
        object[k].forEach(function (a, i)  {
            r[i] = r[i] || {};
            r[i][k] = a;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
}

console.log(pivot({ value1: ["a", "b", "c"], value2: [1, 2, 3] }));
console.log(pivot({ value1: ["a", "b", "c", "d"], value2: [1, 2, 3], value3: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8] }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate the array.

```js
var data = {
  value1: ["a", "b", "c"],
  value2: [1, 2, 3]
};

// iterate over the first property
var res = data.value1.map(function(v, i) {
  // generate the array object element
  return {
    value1: v,
    value2: data.value2[i]
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** If the property names are unknown then you can do something like this.

```js
var data = {
  value1: ["a", "b", "c"],
  value2: [1, 2, 3]
};

// get all property names
var keys = Object.keys(data);

// iterate over the first property name array
var res = data[keys[0]].map(function(v, i) {
  // generate the object by iterating over the keys array
  return keys.reduce(function(obj, k) {
    // define the object property
    obj[k] = data[k][i];
    // return the objet reference
    return obj;
    // set initial value as empty object
  }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** If array length can be different then you need to get the larger array from the collection.

```js
var data = {
  value1: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  value2: [1, 2, 3],
  value3: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
};

// get all property names
var keys = Object.keys(data);

// iterate over the largest array
var res = data[
  // get the largest array holding key from the keys array  
  keys.reduce(function(k, k1) {
    return data[k1].length > data[k].length ? k1 : k;
  })
].map(function(v, i) {
  // generate the object by iterating over the keys array
  return keys.reduce(function(obj, k) {
    // check element exist in the array by comparing
    // the length and index
    if (data[k].length > i)
    // define the property if value exist in index
      obj[k] = data[k][i];
    // return the objet reference
    return obj;
    // set initial value as empty object
  }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This assume both are of the same size.

Comment: @Ghasan :  that's the expected input

Comment: @Ghasan :  I will add solution for that's too

Comment: you like to loooooop. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var data = {
  value1: ["a", "b", "c"],
  value2: [1, 2, 3]
}

var newData  = [];


for (var i=0; i<data.value1.length; i++) {
      var obc = {}
          obc['value1'] = data.value1[i];
          obc['value2'] = data.value2[i];
      newData.push(obc)
}

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
  var data = {
        value1: ["a", "b", "c"],
        value2: [1, 2, 3]
    };
    
    var arr = [];
    
    data[Object.keys(data)[0]].forEach(function (value, index) {
        arr[index] = {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
            arr[index][key]=data[key][index];
        });
    });
    
    console.log(arr)
```

With this solution you can modify the `value1`, `value2` props, or you can add more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
  value1: ["a", "b", "c"],
  value2: [1, 2, 3]
}

var newData = [];

for(var i=0;i<data.value1.length;i++){
   var obj = {
       value1: data.value1[i],
       value2: data.value2[i]
   }
   newData.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: For most answers it is a good idea to add an explanation to show how the code works, this helps other people with less programming experience understand what the code does.